# Using the block theme in production

Tags: block-editor

In the WordPress documentation about block themes written next: "These features are experimental and part of the Gutenberg plugin."
Accordingly, I have a question. Should I use the block theme for a commercial product, or is it still experimental and can be changed in the future without backward compatibility? So, should I instead use traditional themes yet or not?

Comment: there are already commercial block themes, and the default theme for 2022 and 2023 are block themes, are you sure the documentation isn't just old? You should find the link and share it in the Make WP slack #documentation channel

Comment: I've read about the block theme on the WordPress site by the  
[link](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/block-theme-overview/)

Comment: that line hasn't been touched in at least 9 months and was changed in https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/38800 which is a rehash of the previous version. That documentation is community maintained. You're putting too much emphasis on out of date documentation. Block themes are highlighted in the .org theme repo and bundled with WordPress. ***You need to raise this as an issue with the documentation team.***